# Community Create Case Form attachments won't upload: Your case was submitted, but the attachment wasn't saved

Tags: customer-community

**Given**:

- Customer Community
- `Create Case Form` component (not the newer Contact Support component)
- Napili template
- Authenticated customer community users only - no guest users
- Community Users have profile P with read - create - edit on Cases
- Attachments enabled on Create Case Form component
- Observed starting Winter 19
- No triggers on Attachment SObject

**When**

- Authenticated community user clicks button that displays Create Case Form and completes form
- Clicks on Add Attachment, selects file
- Then clicks `Submit` button to submit the case w/ attachment

**RESULT**:

- Case submitted but error in red box appears: `Your case was submitted, but the attachment wasn't saved. Please create a new comment and attach the file to it.`

> So, how do I enable attachments to successfully upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that you need to enable a checkbox associated with attachments on Accounts and Contacts:

```
Setup | Communities Settings |Community Role and User Settings
```

**"Lets customer users access notes and attachments" -- check true**

[image]

This box had been unchecked for the org prior to Winter 19 yet evidence existed community users were able to upload attachments to Cases prior to Winter 19.

Comment: I added this checkbox and still no luck. Everything for me is exactly as it's described in the original quesiton

Comment: @denvergreene - you should ask a new question posing your situation and reference this question/answer.  This will get more community attention

Comment: Could you accept this answer?